# Android 2.1 Browser Javascript Problems and Suggestions

Tags: javascript, android, browser

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4670359/android-2-1-browser-javascript-jquery-metadata-problem) yesterday that has gone unanswered.  So I will just ask this:

What advice can you give me about Android 2.1 Web Browser and Javascript?  How do you debug errors?  What things do you avoid doing?  What things do you make sure to do?

In a lot of ways, the Browser behaves like Mobile Safari on iOS devices.  I need help with what makes it different from iOS devices.

Comment: For debugging, consider [Weinre](http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/). I'm using it all the time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Android SDK is freely available, and includes an emulator that will allow you to run the browser that comes with the OS. So, you can test your site directly in an emulated device, if you don't have a device available.

There are some features for debugging via the SDK as well, see here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/debugging.html

Answer (score 0):

Surely if it works in firefox etc and you have no errors via firebug then it should be fine. But you could try using [firebug lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite) to debug any errors.

I know it this works even in IE6 so it should work in the Android browser.